# Variables that affect histogram plotted with hist() function in R

Tags: r, histogram

In R it is possible to plot the histogram and save it's properties to variable:

```
> h1=hist(c(1,1,2,3,4,5,5), breaks=0.5:5.5)
```

Those properties can be then read:

```
> h1
$breaks
[1] 0.5 1.5 2.5 3.5 4.5 5.5

$counts
[1] 2 1 1 1 2

$density
[1] 0.2857143 0.1428571 0.1428571 0.1428571 0.2857143

$mids
[1] 1 2 3 4 5

$xname
[1] "c(1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5)"

$equidist
[1] TRUE

attr(,"class")
[1] "histogram"
```

How does those properties affect histogram? So far I've figured out following:

The relationship between `$breaks` and `$counts`. `$breaks` represents the interval to which the plotted data may fall and `$counts` represents the amount of data that have fallen into this interval, for example:

[] denotes [closed interval](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ClosedInterval.html) (endpoints are included)

() denotes [open interval](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/OpenInterval.html) (endpoints are not included)

```
BREAKS  : COUNTS
[0.5-1.5] : 2 # There are two 1 which falls into this interval
(1.5-2.5] : 1 # There is one 2 which falls into this interval
(2.5-3.5] : 1 # There is one 3 which falls into this interval
(3.5-4.5] : 1 # There is one 4 which falls into this interval
(4.5-5.5] : 2 # There are two 5 which falls into this interval
```

The relationship between `$breaks` and `$density` is basically the same as above but written in percents, for example:

```
BREAKS  : DENSITY
[0.5-1.5] : 0.2857143 # This interval covers cca 28% of plot
(1.5-2.5] : 0.1428571 # This interval covers cca 14% of plot
(2.5-3.5] : 0.1428571 # This interval covers cca 14% of plot
(3.5-4.5] : 0.1428571 # This interval covers cca 14% of plot
(4.5-5.5] : 0.2857143 # This interval covers cca 28% of plot
```

Of course when you sum all those values you will get 1:

```
> sum(h1$density)
[1] 1
```

Following stands for x-axis name:

```
$xname
[1] "c(1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5)"
```

But what does do the remaining do, especially `$mids`?

```
$mids
[1] 1 2 3 4 5

$equidist
[1] TRUE

attr(,"class")
[1] "histogram"
```

Also the `help(hist)` returns many others, shouldn't they be also listed in above output, if not why? As it is explained in [following](http://planspace.org/20141225-how_does_r_calculate_histogram_break_points/) article

> By default, bin counts include values less than or equal to the bin's
>   right break point and strictly greater than the bin's left break
>   point, except for the leftmost bin, which includes its left break
>   point.

So following:

```
h1=hist(c(1,1,2,3,4,5,5,1.5), breaks=0.5:5.5)
```

will return histogram where 1.5 will fall into 0.5-1.5 interval. One "workaround" is to set interval size smaller e.g.

```
h1=hist(c(1,1,2,3,4,5,5,1.5), breaks=seq(0.5,5.5,0.1))
```

but this seems unpractical to me, and it also adds bunch of 0 to `$counts` and `$density`, is there a better, automatic way?

Except this it also have one side effect that I cannot explain myself: why the last example return in summary 10 and not 1?

```
> sum(h1$density)
[1] 10
> h1$density[h1$density>0]
[1] 2.50 1.25 1.25 1.25 1.25 2.50
```

Comment: Please read `?[functionname]` before posting questions like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Question 1 What do $mids and $equidist mean:
From the help file:

> mids:     the n cell midpoints.
>
> equidist:     logical, indicating if the distances between breaks are all the same.

---

Q2: Yes, with
`h1=hist(c(1,1,2,3,4,5,5,1.5), breaks=0.5:5.5)`
1.5 will fall into the 0.5-1.5 categorie. If you want it to fall into the 1.5-2.5 categorie, you should use:

```
h1=hist(c(1,1,2,3,4,5,5,1.5), breaks=0.49:5.49)
```

or much neater:

```
h1=hist(c(1,1,2,3,4,5,5,1.5), breaks=0.5:5.5, right=FALSE)
```

I'm not sure what you want to automate here, but hopefully the above answers your question. If not please me more clear about your question.

---

Q3
About density being 10 and not 1, that is because densities are no frequencies. From the help file:

> density:
> values f^(x[i]), as estimated density values. If all(diff(breaks) == 1), they are the relative frequencies counts/n and in general satisfy sum[i; f^(x[i]) (b[i+1]-b[i])] = 1, where b[i] = breaks[i].

So if your breaks are not equal to 1, density will not sum up to 1.

Comment: Thank you for reply, I'm not native English speaker so I did not catch the idea behind `mids` even from help. If I understand it correct then it is center of particular vertical bar? Regarding last question I've found this that will return 1 `sum(h$density * diff(h$breaks))`

Comment: I am no native speaker either, but I understand the same: it is the middle of the class of a histogram, if the class is 2.5-3.5, the mid will be 3.